# Linux Device Drivers tutorial make

Tags: linux, kernel

Hi I am very new to kernel development and am following this [tutorial](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch02.pdf)
.

When I try to make module:

```
    #include <linux/init.h>
    #include <linux/module.h>
    MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
    static int hello_init(void)
    {
     printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");
     return 0;
    }
    static void hello_exit(void)
    {
     printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
    }
    module_init(hello_init);
    module_exit(hello_exit);
```

using "make" and the makefile as written in the book.

```
    obj-m := hello.o
```

I get error

> make: *** no targets. stop.

Please help and Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

a sample [`Makefile`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html):

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

The `linux-headers` (kernel-headers) and the `build-essential` (development-tools) should be installed.